# completion of space $C^\infty_0(D)$ to $H^0_1(D)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Given $D$ be bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

given space $C^\infty_0(D)$ with inner product norm defined by $(f,g) = \int_D\sum f_ig_i dx$ where $f_i = \partial_if$

Now we can complete the space of $C^\infty_0(D)$ to new one denoted $H^0_1(D)$.

The question here is why the functions in the completion has first order partial derivative.Do we need to extend the partial derivative operator here also to $H^0_1(D)$?

Comment: Yes, the partials exist as weak derivatives only, see e.g. evans chapter 5

Comment: thank you.I got it